# Add a new image in jquery and make it clickable

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add an image in jquery and then make it clickable I have maked the following code below but it does not work.

It adds the images but it will not make it clickable.

```
 $(".HeaderGifs").click(function() { 
 alert("It Works");
 }); 


 $("#show_images").val()).append("<img class='HeaderGifs' src='images/text.jpg'></img>");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want an element with a particular class to always respond to the click event, you need to use one of jQuery's methods to do this. When you just use `click()`, you're basically telling jQuery to only apply that event listener to elements with that class *right now*, instead of for every element present and future. For this purpose, jQuery has the `on()` method:

```
$('.HeaderGifs').on('click', function() {....}
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

**Edit**: I should also mention the `delegate()` method, just in case you find more value in doing it this way:

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: also noticed, it should just be $("#show_images").append(...);

Answer (score 0):

use `.live()` to add event handlers to elements that you create after page load

Answer (score 0):

For binding to the elements occuring or inserted in the future (like in your case you are inserting whole `img` tag later ) you have to use `.live()` or `.delegate()` functions.

The detailed documentation for both are available below -

[.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

[.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Answer (score 0):

To make only image clickable use the code below:

```
$('.HeaderGifs').on('click',"img",function() {....}
```